# A Filipino teacher taught that "women are treated unequal"! Right or Wrong?

Tags: grammaticality

A Filipino teacher taught that "*women are treated unequal*". I think it should be "*unequally*".

Is there any structure "*to treat someone adjective*" in English?

Does "*to treat me bad*" make any sense?

Searching "*treat her bad*" & "*treat her badly*" on Google returns more than 50000 & 48000 results respectively

Comment: It should be adverb, you are right.  However, sometimes adjectives are used as adverbs.

Comment: what about : Searching "treat her bad" & "treat her badly" on Google returns more than 50000 & 48000 results respectively

Comment: ["All men are created equal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_men_are_created_equal) is straight out of the Declaration of Independence of a certain natively English-speaking country, so if to say "created unequal" is incorrect, then so must be "created equal". Just an observation.

Comment: @  Mentalist, grammar in the past may be different from now?

Comment: Created (to be) equal, grammar is not to be blamed.

Comment: @Mentalist - "Created equal" is a different statement than "created equally," and neither is incorrect.  This is a distinctly different construction than "treated equal," it is wrong to take them as parallel.

Comment: @Mentalist equal in this case is a predicative adjunct.

Comment: @GEdgar please see this topic http://english.stackexchange.com/q/279065/129806

Comment: @michael_timofeev Thank you for the link. I added a paragraph to my answer below. Consider this Aristotle quotation: "equals should be treated equally and unequals unequally." The word _(un)equally_ is widely used to describe actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to describe *how* women are treated. It's an adverb that answers the question of *how*, *when*, or *where*, not an adjectives. So you should say:

> Women are treated *unequally*.

By the way, there are special verbs that are followed by adjectives. Read about them [here](http://www.nativespeakeronline.com/learning-english/english-grammar/sense-verbs-with-adverbs).

Google searches in the whole Web, which is not a reliable corpus to learn a language from. You can use a good dictionary with lots of examples, or if you like to find examples for yourself, you can use one of these [corpora](https://www.english-corpora.org/).
In this case, if you do search in the [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), you'll find results like these (which are far from *treating someone (un)equal*):

- *They are taught to treat all people with equal respect.*
- *You will long for him to treat you as an equal.*
- *... by telling them that they have to treat women like equal and ...*
- *I have to treat her like an equal.*

In the same way you shouldn't say "*to treat someone bad*". Then again, in an informal style speakers sometimes use adjectives instead of adverbs. This is one of the many rules that some people bend to speak in a more relaxed and casual way. You can read about that [here](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/181465-Native-speakers-like-to-use-adjectives-instead-of-adverbs).

And, you can read about predicative adjuncts under [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/279065/why-adjective-can-be-placed-after-eat-as-in-garlic-can-be-eaten-raw). This is another case where you can have an adjective after a verb, but that is not the case here. Because here you want to describe the action (to treat), not the object (women).

Comment: You might want to look at this topic to see why this answer is incorrect. http://english.stackexchange.com/q/279065/129806

Comment: @michael_timofeev Thank you. I added a paragraph to my answer. Consider this Aristotle quotation: "equals should be treated equally and unequals unequally." The word _(un)equally_ is widely used to describe actions.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it should be "treated unequally."  "Treat me bad" is also ungrammatical, but it is a long-standing idiom that doesn't sound odd to native ears.